# Changing google map location

Tags: android

Here is my code for display a location in a map using iframe,
How can i change the current location?How can i change the api key?
 im bit confused with the location.
Please help me to solve the issue

```
        String iframe = "<iframe src=https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m16!1m12!1m3!1d434549.40374533384!2d74.24349628287739!3d31.690830957117996!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sPakistan+Lahore!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1395138949280 width=600 height=450 frameborder=0 style=border:0</iframe>";
        googleMapWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.googlemap_webView);
        googleMapWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        googleMapWebView.loadData(iframe, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: why don't you use the mapFragment? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: This method is simple and perfect for my purpose thats why.It is working perfectly bur i need to change the location.

Comment: so, it's not perfect, after all...